# How do I send a multipartFile using spring RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I am trying to POST a file to from one SpringBoot app to anothe SpringBoot app.
The enpoint I am trying to reach looks like

```
@PostMapping(
        value = "/upload",
        consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ArmResponse<JobData>> uploadInvoices(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile interestingStuff) {

    String incomingFilename = interestingStuff.getName();
    String originalFilename = interestingStuff.getOriginalFilename();
    String contentType = interestingStuff.getContentType();

    // do interesting stuff here

    return ok(successfulResponse(new JobData()));
}
```

The code in the app performing the POST request to thios endpoint looks like

```
public void loadInvoices(MultipartFile invoices) throws IOException {

    File invoicesFile = new File(invoices.getOriginalFilename());
    invoices.transferTo(invoicesFile);

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    parts.add("file", invoicesFile);


    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parts, httpHeaders);

    String url = String.format("%s/rest/inbound/invoices/upload", baseUrl);

    final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
    messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<Source>());

    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(messageConverters);

    template.exchange(
            url,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            httpEntity,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<ArmResponse<JobData>>() {

            });
}
```

If I post the file in a form using postman - it works
The content-type header on the request from Postman looks like

```
content-type:"multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------286899320410555838190774"
```

When the POST is performed by the RestTemplate I get the following error.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]

I suspect that the content-type header being sent in the request is wrong.
Does anyone know how to correctly set the content-type header for MULTIPART_FORM_DATA?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple, as usual. Simply call getResource() on the multipartFile.

```
public void loadInvoices(MultipartFile invoices) throws IOException {

    Resource invoicesResource = invoices.getResource();

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    parts.add("file", invoicesResource);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(parts, httpHeaders);

    restTemplate.postForEntity("my/url", httpEntity, SommeClass.class);
}
```

Comment: My problem has been solved by `invices.getResource( )`, thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

A slightly prettier solution in Kotlin:

```
    @Test
    fun testMultipartUpload() {
        val bytes = ByteArray(10240) // Get your bytes however you like.
        val resource = object : ByteArrayResource(bytes) {
            override fun getFilename() = "xyzzy.jpg"
        }
        val request = RequestEntity.post("/foobar")
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .body(LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Any>().apply { add("data", resource) })
        val result = testRestTemplate.exchange(request, FooBar::class.java)
        Assertions.assertTrue(result.statusCode.is2xxSuccessful)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need messageConverters? Just simply use the code like in this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
  .postForEntity(url , httpEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I pretty much started with that exact tutorial. i expected it to work, but it does not. I get the error mentioned in my question. I added the MessageConverters as part of my many attempts to get it working. Removing them now and going back to the vanilla solution from the tutorial, I will see if it works.

Comment: No I still get; "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
arm-ui_1   |  at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]